# Table layout structure

Tags: html, css

I want my table layout to be like this:

[image]

At this moment my table is looking like this:

[image]

The "*Carrinho de compras*" button must be bellow everything.

I tried changing some stuff like put `<th></th>` for the `imagem`, but it didn't work, it stayed on the left side of the `nome`.

Code of table:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="4px" style="display: inline-block; ">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <?php echo '<img STYLE="width="150" height="150";" src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['imagem']).'"/>';?>
</tr>
<th>
    <?php echo $row['nome']; ?>
</th>
<tr class="record">
    <td>REF:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ref']; ?></td>
    <td>Preço:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></td>
    <tr><form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="paypal">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['preco']; ?>">

            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_PT/PT/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - A forma mais fácil e segura de efetuar pagamentos online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_PT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
    </tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS code:

```
        #tb {
        width: 100px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-top: -400px;
        margin-left: 260px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 1em;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color:blue;
    }   

    th {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
        border: 0;
    }
```

And don't worry about the borders, and the colours, I just want the structure done.

Comment: 1 - You can't put an image in a Table row (TR) ... 
2 - You can't just have a TH which isn't in a Table row ... 
3 - It looks like you need colSpan on your (intended) header row ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So how can I make my images appear on top of the tables?? @TonyDuffill

Comment: I don't fully understand your intention - if your example is a table, then you just need to follow the Table structure rules ... <tr><td>data or image</td></tr> ... but given your last row has 4 columns, you need <td colspan='4'> for the first 2 rows. Please look up how to format tables, or better still, use divs for your solution.

Comment: Sorry, you probably don't need colspan='4' because the last row is a form - but you still can't just put a form in a TR without a TD (or TH). As I say, consider using divs...

Comment: You have lots of other errors as well. HTML is very forgiving of errors, but you shouldn't be surprised that the browser thinks you meant other things than you did. Run your page through the W3C validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done :

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="4px" style="display: inline-block; ">
<tbody>
<th  colspan="4">
    <img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $row['imagem']; ?>" />
</th>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <?php echo $row['nome']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="record">
    <td>REF:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ref']; ?></td>
    <td>Preço:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></td>
```